# imp.find_module ImportError: No module name

Tags: python, windows, module, path, importerror

I am very new at python and getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kzul\Documents\Stigma-demo-game-master\testw32\testing.py", line 44, in <module>
    dam = test().getClass('hello', 'dam')
  File "C:\Users\kzul\Documents\Stigma-demo-game-master\testw32\testing.py", line 40, in getClass
    objmod = self._impoter(modules, klass)
  File "C:\Users\kzul\Documents\Stigma-demo-game-master\testw32\testing.py", line 24, in _impoter
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(pathmod)
ImportError: No module named hello\dam
```

I don't have any idea why python in wndows gave me this error, but in my Linux it run smoothly. it says no module **hello\dam** :(

Here's my directory about dam file

```
C:\Users\kzul\Documents\Stigma-demo-game-master\testw32\hello\dam.py
```

Here's the code I running on my cmd

```
C:\Users\kzul\Documents\Stigma-demo-game-master\testw32>python testing.py
```

And the code inside **testw32\testing.py**

```
import sys, imp
from os import path
from hello.dam import dam

class test:
    def _impoter(self, instance, substance):
        pathmod = path.join(instance, substance)
        try:
            return sys.modules[pathmod]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(pathmod)

        try:
            return imp.load_module(pathmod, fp, pathname, description)
        finally:
            if fp:
                fp.close()

    def getClass(self, modules, klass):
        objmod = self._impoter(modules, klass)
        klass = getattr(objmod, klass)
        return klass()

dam = test().getClass('hello', 'dam')
dam().hello()
```

Code inside file **testw32\hello\dam.py**

```
class dam:
    def hello(self):
        print 'you did it'
```

I had set *PYTHONPATH*, *PYTHONHOME* and *PATH* on environtment variable in windows but still not working :(

Comment: I'm not sure why it works on linux but are you using packages (is there a `__init__.py` file in the folder) and wouldn't it make more sense to use `'.'.join((instance, substance))` instead of `path.join()` since packages are separated by a dot instead of a `/`?

Comment: yes I including `__init__.py` on my packages. hmm well since the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) say `imp.find_module(name[, path])` so I follow it. well it works using `'.'.join((instance, substance))` , thanks mate :)

Comment: well you import the module with `import hello.dam` so the string you pass to `imp.find_module` needs to be `"hello.dam"` for it to work the same way as importing, still surprised the slash works on linux though.